# solr out of sync from cassandra

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

I installed DSE (datastax enterprise) 4.8 on a 3-nodes cluster. 2 nodes have solr enabled, and 1 node has spark. My snitch is PropertyFileSnitch, in cassandra-topology.properties, 2 DCs are defined: node1, node 2 are DC1:rack1, node 3 are DC2:rack1. My autoSoftCommit maxTime is set to 30 seconds.

I created a table with id and status fields. Then create core on this table.

I can insert data to Cassandra, after a little while, the data is searchable. Then I updated status field from 1 to 11. After that the index has never updated. I can query st:1, but st:11 fails to return correct answer. In the returned the record, the status field is actually 11 (both solr_query and solr web API).

Comment: My keyspace replication strategy is : DC1: 2, DC2: 1